# JavaScript fancybox "conflict wrapper" code, how does it work?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I came across this piece of code:

```
(function($) {

    $("a img").fancybox({

        ... some more Fancybox code ...

    });

})(jQuery);
```

In the tutorial the guy calls this a "conflict wrapper"...

However, I have no idea, how this code works. Maybe my Javascript is a bit rusty, but can someone explain to me step by step how this code works?

How is this function called, where does it get $ passed from, from the fancy-code inside of it?

I just don't understand this construct...

Comment: or is this something fancybox-specific?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> where does it get $ passed from

From here: `(jQuery)` – that’s simply the global jQuery object passed to the function, for the parameter `$`, so that jQuery can be accessed as `$` inside the function, even if `$` is not available outside (because jQuery might run in no-conflict mode.)

> How is this function called

It is called immeditately – because it has `(…)` at the end, which is what is used to call functions in JS, plain and simple.

Go look up the term **IIFE**, if you need more information about the whole concept of an immediately invoked function.

Answer (score 1):

> How is this function called

This is a Immediately Invoking Function Expression [IIFE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Immediately-invoked_function_expression) which is executed as soon as it is defined 
Note

```
(function($) {
^ this brace 
 // Rest of code

})(jQuery);
 ^^ These braces
```

> where does it get $ passed from

It is passed from `})(jQuery)`,which is global jQuery object. You can make also pass other variables like

```
(function(a,$) {
    console.log(a) // Will log Hello
     // Rest of code

    })("Hello",jQuery);
```